# flutter how save a picture from camera to device?

Tags: camera, flutter, save, gallery

I'm trying to save a picture from camera in a real device, but can't find a way.

By now I get it saved in a File, but can't get it in the gallery..

My code at this moment is:

```
File _imagenTemporal;

String _opcion = "";

var imagen; 

Future getImagen(String opcion) async {

  if (opcion == "camara") {

    imagen = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

  } else if (opcion == "galeria") {

    imagen = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

  }

  setState(() {
    _imagenTemporal = imagen;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 11):

This plugin
https://pub.dev/packages/gallery_saver
saves images and videos from camera or network to local storage(both Android and iOS)

This is how it's used:

```
GallerySaver.saveVideo(path)
GallerySaver.saveImage(path)
```

path is local path or network url.

It returns Future - true if it was saved successfully and false if it wasn't(for any reason).

Comment: This was by far the easiest solution for me, thx - works on my android phone

Answer (score 8):

You can persist the `Image` taken using the [google's path provider plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/path_provider):

- Path to local storage:

  ```
  directory = getApplicationDocumentsDirectory() // AppData folder path

  directory = getExternalStorageDirectory() // main storage folders path,but only works on android as IOS is not currently supported.

  path = directory.path ;
  ```
- Copy `imagen` file to the path you got in the previous step using `copy` fuction:

  ```
  File savedImage = await imagen.copy('$path/saved_image.jpg');
  ```

These `Image`s stored by this methodology can be accessed using your `Files` application and indexed in your `Gallery` or `Photos` app depending on the platform.You can find more information on [official cookbook read and write files](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files) and [path provider API documentation](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/path_provider/latest/).

Comment: Then use the `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()`, but you have to test whether the image will appear in your `Photos` app.

Answer (score 5):

I've just written [album_saver](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/album_saver) plugin for this

This can work on both IOS and Android.

```
import 'package:album_saver/album_saver.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

File image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

// Save to ablum
AlbumSaver.saveToAlbum(filePath: image.path, albumName: "YourAlbumName");

// Create album
// In Android, it will create a folder in DCIM folder
AlbumSaver.createAlbum(albumName: "YourAlbumName");

// Get DCIM folder path (just work on Android)
AlbumSaver.getDcimPath();
```

Comment: @MuhammadFaizan Yes, It will work with `ImageSource.camera`

Comment: How could you change image name?

Answer (score 2):

I tried a lot of flutter plugins to save image, and only this one works. [Gallery_saver v1.0.7](https://pub.dev/packages/gallery_saver)

But the example has a little error thats why i wasn't able to run it. Here's the correct example:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:gallery_saver/gallery_saver.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String firstButtonText = 'Take photo';
  String secondButtonText = 'Record video';
  double textSize = 20;

  @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Flexible(
              flex: 1,
              child: Container(
                child: SizedBox.expand(
                      child: RaisedButton(
                color: Colors.blue,
                onPressed: _takePhoto,
                child: Text(firstButtonText,
                    style:
                        TextStyle(fontSize: textSize, color: Colors.white)),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Flexible(
          child: Container(
              child: SizedBox.expand(
            child: RaisedButton(
              color: Colors.white,
              onPressed: _recordVideo,
              child: Text(secondButtonText,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: textSize, color: Colors.blueGrey)),
            ),
          )),
          flex: 1,
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
));
  }

  void _takePhoto() async {
    ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera).then((File recordedImage) {
  if (recordedImage != null && recordedImage.path != null) {
    setState(() {
      firstButtonText = 'saving in progress...';
    });
    GallerySaver.saveImage(recordedImage.path).then((path) {
      setState(() {
        firstButtonText = 'image saved!';
      });
    });
  }
});
  }

  void _recordVideo() async {
    ImagePicker.pickVideo(source: ImageSource.camera)
        .then((File recordedVideo) {
      if (recordedVideo != null && recordedVideo.path != null) {
        setState(() {
          secondButtonText = 'saving in progress...';
        });
        GallerySaver.saveVideo(recordedVideo.path).then((path) {
          setState(() {
            secondButtonText = 'video saved!';
          });
        });
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*My solution for this problem is SharedPreferences - store FileName.path as a String and restore to File(path); maybe this will help for someone *

```
 //global variables:
  File imageFile;
  String finalPath;

  //store string value
  Future<void> storeSharedPrefs(String key, String value) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.setString(key, value);
  }

  //restore string value
  Future<String> restoreSharedPrefs(String key, String inputValue) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final value = prefs.getString(key);

    if (value == null) {
      return null;
    }

    setState(() {
      inputValue = value;
    });

    return inputValue;
  }

  //load saves
  void loadPrefs() async {
    try {
      //restore saved shared prefs:
      finalPath = await restoreSharedPrefs('image', finalPath);

      //load imageFile with restored shared prefs path:
      this.setState(() {
        if (finalPath != null) imageFile = File(finalPath);
      });
      debugPrint('restored path is: $finalPath');
    } catch (e) {
      print('loading error: $e');
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadPrefs();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

pickImage is deprecated. You should use ImagePicker.getImage().

[More Information](https://androidride.com/flutter-notes-taking-app-tutorial/)

[image]

Use below code to store the photo from camera or gallery.

```
//getImage(ImageSource.camera) or getImage(ImageSource.gallery)

void getImage(ImageSource imageSource) async {
    PickedFile imageFile = await picker.getImage(source: imageSource);
    if (imageFile == null) return;
    File tmpFile = File(imageFile.path);
    final appDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final fileName = basename(imageFile.path);
    localFile = await tmpFile.copy('${appDir.path}/$fileName');
    setState(() {
      _image = localFile;
    
    });
  }
```